# SDL window not closing properly

Tags: c, events, sdl

I've got an SDL window which will take a while to close once the cross is pressed. I've got things going on in the event loop so I think it might be something to do with that. I've got a similar SDL window which closes instantly, but it's not doing anything during the event loop, only checking for the cross.

My code for the event loops is this:

```
while(event.type != SDL_QUIT){
  while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0){
     if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(1);
     }
     flashingText(data, fontdata, display, text);
  }
  SDL_Delay(100);
}
```

In the `flashingText` function there is some SDL delays and SDL rendering?

Comment: `exit(1)` means that the program closes because of an error due to an incorrect function. You should put `exit(0)` when the program closes because the user presses the cross because that means there isn't any error. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) is a complete list of what argument you should use in the `exit()` function under which circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

The delay happens because `flashingText()` was called for **every** event polled, and the more mouse moves within the window, the more events are fired and polled by the loop. Consider this code (which uses the above event polling);

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{    
        SDL_Window* window;
        SDL_Renderer* renderer;

        // Initialize SDL.
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
                return 1;

        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL_RenderClear",
                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                        512, 512,
                        0);

        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 128, 128, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

  // OP's code starts
  SDL_Event event;
  while(event.type != SDL_QUIT){
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
       if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
          SDL_Quit();
          exit(1);
       }
          SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
          // to simulate OP's flashingText()
          SDL_Delay(50);            
    }
    SDL_Delay(100);
  }
  // OP's code ends

  return 0;
}
```

You'll find that the more mouse scrolls/moves within the window area, the more delay for the program to exit.

Hope that helps.

Cheers.